# Can't request POST method in NginX

Tags: node.js, nginx

I deploy node application on cloud and cloud use nginx for reverse proxy I can request GET method but I can't request POST method. Please help me for allow POST method.

My config

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        root /var/www/html;

        server_name localhost;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                # try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
                proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
                proxy_redirect off;
        }
}
```

And error log in NginX show

```
2017/03/14 09:21:00 [warn] 10102#10102: invalid value "POST" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:58
2017/03/14 09:21:00 [warn] 10105#10105: invalid value "POST" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:58
2017/03/14 10:17:10 [error] 13483#13483: *6 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: xxx.xx.xx.xxx, server: localhost, request: "POST /api/v1/users/$
2017/03/14 10:21:42 [error] 13483#13483: *11 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: xxx.xx.xx.xxx, server: localhost, request: "POST /api/v1/users$
```

Comment: What do you do and what do you get?

Comment: I want to deploy web service I can use get but can not use post

Comment: And I want allow post method.

Comment: I see what you want. I don't see what error do you get. Show request and response

Comment: I update error log from NginX in detail question.

Comment: Are you closing your stream? By `res.end();`

Comment: No I don't closing.